# How would I parse this string in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on a string from a json_encode output:

```
$string = ["Item1","Item2","Item3"]
```

I want to get only the values Item1, Item2 and Item3 from this string. I believe that the explode() function can only be used by one character like this:

```
$result=explode(",",$string);
```

How would I parse this string if I have special characters as shown above?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `json_decode`? should parse it for you-

Answer (score 0):

In that **particular** example, you've got a simple PHP array, so you can do this:

```
list($item1, $item2, $item3) = $string;
```

Otherwise assuming your `$string` variable contains that data **wrapped in quotes** to make it a string, you'll simply need to `json_decode()` the data with the second paramter passing in boolean true to return an array:

```
list($item1, $item2, $item3) = json_decode($string, true);
```